# Jenkins docker-build-step plugin is not able to push image to docker cloud

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am trying to build and push image to docker cloud with Jenkins using the `docker-build-step` plugin. Added password for docker hub with Jenkins Password Manager plugin.

I am doing this in two steps. First step uses `Build/Create Image` command. The command builds image and tags it with build ID.

Second step pushes image to docker hub. Here is console trace:

```
[Docker] INFO: Build image id:5240329f9db6
[Docker] INFO: Pushing image parthmodi/docker_demo:test_push
[Docker] INFO: PushResponseItem[stream=<null>,status=The push refers to a repository [docker.io/parthmodi/docker_demo],progressDetail=<null>,progress=<null>,id=<null>,from=<null>,time=<null>,errorDetail=<null>,error=<null>,aux=<null>]
```

...

```
[Docker] INFO: PushResponseItem[stream=<null>,status=<null>,progressDetail=<null>,progress=<null>,id=<null>,from=<null>,time=<null>,errorDetail=ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=<null>,message=denied: requested access to the resource is denied],error=denied: requested access to the resource is denied,aux=<null>]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.PushImageResultCallback.awaitSuccess(PushImageResultCallback.java:49)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.PushImageCommand.execute(PushImageCommand.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:74)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:496)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Build step 'Execute Docker command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is complete trace:
https://pastebin.com/tFy399D5

Why am I getting `Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied` error for pushing image to Docker Registry, and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: if its private dockerhub repo with username & password then you have to pass it jenkins , https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/docker-hub-20-integration-cloudbees-jenkins-platform

Answer (score 1):

Had also similar issues as OP, but with the Ram Kamath's code example. The issue lied with the incorrect registryURL that I passed to the `docker.withRegistry`. I had it as `https://index.docker.io/v2/` but the credentials were for the `https://index.docker.io/v1/` API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
stage('build and publish'){
def dockerImage = docker.build('dockerImageName')
docker.withRegistry(RegistryURL, CredentialID) {
       dockerImage.push('latest')
}
}
```

Comment: How and where to use this script?

Comment: Did the above answer help?